# change external output resolution

Tags: android, sdk, settings, resolution

Is it possible to change the external resolution of a hdmi-output in an android mobile?
No review goes that deep, just telling, they're able to play HD, but not, if android is able to change settings manually..

is there any function in the sdk?

Answer (score 0):

Came back to share my solution for those who also come across this.

On my Note3 running Lollipop I was able to check for supported external resolutions by running ( via a terminal app or adb shell )

```
>dmesg
```

and ( filtering with grep ) looking for the lines:

```
<6>[  581.051746] hdmi_edid_add_sink_video_format: EDID: format: 1 [640x480 p60 4/3], Supported
<6>[  581.051756] hdmi_edid_add_sink_video_format: EDID: format: 1 [640x480 p60 4/3], Supported by MHL
<6>[  581.051767] hdmi_edid_add_sink_video_format: EDID: format: 16 [1920x1080 p60 16/9], Supported
<6>[  581.051777] hdmi_edid_add_sink_video_format: EDID: format: 16 [1920x1080 p60 16/9], Not-Supported by MHL
<6>[  581.051790] hdmi_edid_add_sink_video_format: EDID: format: 4 [1280x 720 p60 16/9], Supported
<6>[  581.051801] hdmi_edid_add_sink_video_format: EDID: format: 4 [1280x 720 p60 16/9], Supported by MHL
<6>[  581.051812] hdmi_edid_add_sink_video_format: EDID: format: 133 [1280x1024 p60 5/4], Not-Supported
<6>[  581.051822] hdmi_edid_add_sink_video_format: EDID: format: 133 [1280x1024 p60 5/4], Not-Supported by MHL
<6>[  581.051833] hdmi_edid_add_sink_video_format: EDID: format: 132 [1024x768 p60 4/3], Not-Supported
<6>[  581.051843] hdmi_edid_add_sink_video_format: EDID: format: 132 [1024x768 p60 4/3], Not-Supported by MHL
```

which you'll note correspond to supported resolutions in:

```
>cat /sys/devices/virtual/graphics/fb1/edid_modes 
1,4
```

then select your preferred output using :

```
>setprop hw.hdmi.resolution 1
```

and then re-plug the mhl adapter.

which in my case resulted in 640x480 which was the only option supported by my 800x600 projector.

Thanks to this [StackExchange answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/114693/force-720p-resolution-on-inforce-6540)!

Comment: I am trying to solve a similar issue.  When I type "adb shell dmesg" I receive "klogctl: Operation not permitted".  I am using adb with an Android Samsung Galaxy S4 phone.  Any ideas how to run dmesg?

Comment: I ddg'ed (searched)  your error message and came across this solution: 'echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/dmesg_restrict'

Comment: I will give that a try.  Did you have to have the Note3 rooted to be able to use "setprop"  to change the resolution?

Comment: Yes, my Note3 is rooted. Were you able to do it without root?

Comment: It was impossible to do without root.  Is there any good freeware you would recommend to root the phone I am using?  It is a Samsung Galaxy S4 running Android.